# Saber un key y value con For iterator (DataSnapshot), Firebase - Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase

**tengo un problema con el for iterator (DataSnapshot)** ya que en mi app tengo un EditText en el cual cuando ingresas un numero se compara con todos los "key" que hay en la base de datos Firebase y sí ese numero ingresado es igual a algun "key" se muestra el "value" del mismo en un TextView.

Por el momento tengo solo 5 "keys" con sus respectivos "values" **pero mi problema es** que cuando consulto el valor del *key 1, 2, 3 o 4* me dice que no existe (por la sentencia *else* de mi código), sin embargo, si consulto el valor del *key 5* me dice el value correspondiente, en este caso "Texto 5".

Esta es la estructura de la base de datos:

[image: Estructura]

Y este es el código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private TextView mEstado ;
private Button B_buscar;
private EditText E_buscar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("no_orden");

    mEstado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.estado);
    B_buscar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B_buscar);
    E_buscar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.E_buscar);
    final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    B_buscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String buscar = E_buscar.getText().toString().trim();

            mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + postSnapshot.getKey());
                            Log.d(TAG, "Value: " + postSnapshot.getValue());

                        if (postSnapshot.getKey().equals(buscar)){
                           mEstado.setText("El numero #" + buscar + " tiene como texto: " + postSnapshot.getValue());

                        }else{
                            if (buscar.equals("")){
                                mEstado.setText("Ingrese un numero valido.");
                            }else {
                                mEstado.setText("El numero #" + buscar + " no existe.");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
}}
```

**Creo que el problema es que** solo esta leyendo el ultimo valor "almacenado". Como pueden ver a continuación en el Android Monitor si me muestra todos los valores pero a la hora de correrlo en mi dispositivo como ya mencione dice que no existe (por la sentencia else que tengo declarada).

[image: Keys]

Y esto es a la hora de ejecutarlo en mi dispositivo:
[image: Sin funcionar]

**Una disculpa si esta algo extenso, queria plantear mi problema lo mas claro posible con fotos y codigo.**
Gracias.

Comment: has imprimido el valor de los key? Si no lo has hecho, utiliza el `Log.i()` para imprimirlo. Y, cual es le tipo de dato de las claves y los valores?

Comment: Los imprimi por medio del Log.d y ambos valores son String

Comment: El texto de la imagen de la izquierda no corresponde con esto: `El numero #" + buscar + " no existe."`, por tanto, no está entrando ahí... ¿no tendrás alguna confusión o estarás llamando otro método? como lo tienes debería funcionar. ¿Dónde está la parte del código que imprime `La orden #  no existe.`? No la veo por ninguna parte, por eso digo que debes estar confundiéndote de método o algo.

Comment: Esque le cambie el texto que se muestra cuando tome el screenshot de la izquierda.. una disculpa, pero si es el mismo método. Y si yo pienso lo mismo que deberia funcionar pero solo hace bien el ultimo key :(

Comment: Ya. Es que como estás en un bucle sigue comparando todos, entonces debes agregar un `break` si la condición se cumple: **`mEstado.setText("El numero #" + buscar + " tiene como texto: " + postSnapshot.getValue()); break;`** Por eso sólo funcionaba con el último valor, porque en ese caso la condición se cumplía y no seguía leyendo.

Comment: Vaya que me has hecho el día amigo  muchísimas gracias.. si se me ocurrió ponerlo pero lo puse en otro lado. En fin gracias te lo agradezco mucho ✌

Comment: Por favor lee: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta a mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que estás leyendo todos los valores, el bucle debería pararse cuando la condición requerida se cumpla.

Eso lo puedes hacer mediante `break` en este caso:

```
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + postSnapshot.getKey());
                        Log.d(TAG, "Value: " + postSnapshot.getValue());

                    if (postSnapshot.getKey().equals(buscar)){
                       mEstado.setText("El numero #" + buscar + " tiene como texto: " + postSnapshot.getValue());
                       break;
                    }else{
                        if (buscar.equals("")){
                            mEstado.setText("Ingrese un numero valido.");
                        }else {
                            mEstado.setText("El numero #" + buscar + " no existe.");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Al no pararse, seguía comparando hasta alcanzar el último valor.